# @model for _layout.cshtml on MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I was wondering if there's a way to specify a model for the _layout.cshtml file, i've seen lots of posts with the basic same question with people replying with "alternative" solutions, not saying it's not possible nor showing how exactly we could achieve this

having some experience with webforms I've been trying to migrate to MVC and often find myself with such questions, I've found this website: http://blog.bitdiff.com/2012/05/sharing-common-view-model-data-in.html
which partially solved my problem but even them don't bind their _layout.cshtml with a @model, as far as I know, I have to specify a model on each view if I want to access the SharedContext, please correct if I'm wrong

what I wanted to do is declare a "@model Namespace.MyModel" on _layout.cshtml so it could retrieve its information by itself, instead of having to implement a model for each view inherinting from the LayoutModel

*I hope I'm being clear, basically, I wanted to know how can I declare @model tag on a _layout.cshtml so it can access its own model

with the solution I linked before (even though it's not linked to my question) I have to do:
@(((BaseController)ViewContext.Controller).Context.Property) to get the shared information, and if I could simply declare (and use) a @model instead, I could accomplish the same thing by doing something like: @Model.Property*

as you can see, im struggling trying to migrate whatever I already know from webforms to MVC and it's being quite difficult for me since I have to adopt certain practices which are completely different from what I'm used to

thanks in advance

Comment: Why does your _layout need a model?

Comment: that's because I wanted to access the "shared" (Session) information, more specifically, I have a random background that is generated on each new web session and the url is used on _layout.cshtml

Comment: Okay, having a model in _layout is not a good idea, you could use the ViewBag for that - check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267727/most-elegant-way-to-ensure-view-model-data-for-layout-cshtml

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to avoid (the ViewBag), I thought it would be possible to have a strong typing on my layout instead of relying on the ViewBag to avoid small things like mistyping a property, I wanted to rely on the compiler

Comment: _layout is a partial used by all of your views. Specifying a model there would add restriction to every view on your site to also have that model.

Comment: As an alternative to `ViewBag` you can also use a child action.

Comment: @leandrokoiti - you are avoiding one "bad practice" (dynamic typing of ViewBag), but trying to replace it with another bad practice (tying your layout to model data). Layouts should not rely on data...

Comment: @James but wouldn't be correct in this case to have a model tied to any view that uses the layout? since every will use _layout and therefore they would need that property as well?

Comment: @Jasen you mean in this case I should try to create a child action to render the style containing the background in the _layout instead of trying to "attach" my _layout to a model?

Comment: @leandrokoiti Can you give an example of what information you are needing to display in your _layout?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin you are right, I didn't stop to think that way, I'm going to try what Jhoon Bey posted and see how the child action would work as Jasen commented, thank you very much!

Comment: @James basically I have a random background image that needs to be shown every time a new web session is created (the image url persists through a web session, but every time a new web session is created another url is generated), this background is set on the <head> of the _layout file

Comment: I believe that the suggestion that Jasen gave me worked well, if I got it right, I created a child action which simply renders this <style> containing the background image and rendered it as a child action inside the _layout, I guess that solves the problem of replacing one bad practice with another as EkoostikMartin noticed, right?

Comment: From what you just said, you should just use JQuery.

Comment: @James you mean to request the background file from the server through ajax and display it? wouldn't be more work than rendering a child action? I didn't think about the jQuery solution though

Comment: You will probably find `RenderAction` is just going to generate the same kind of code actually. So just do which ones sits best with you.

Comment: @James thank you so much for the insight, the RenderAction did the job and I guess it solved the bad practice problem noted by EkoostikMartin, thank you so much for taking your time for helping me out!

Comment: @leandrokoiti yes, but it seems you figured it out while I was away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you already accepted an answer, based on your saying you are just pulling an image URL you should do it using JQuery, not a model.

This code is untested, apologies for that. Feel free to point out if I typed a bug. The HTML element containing the background image has the `id="url"` attribute so the selectors work.

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetSessionUrl()
{
    //logic to detmine url
    return url;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $url = $('#url');
    var options = {
        url: "/Home/GetSessionUrl",
        type: "get",
        async:false
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        $url.attr('src', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: hey James thanks again for taking your time, I switched to your answer because you stated that a model is not suited for this job in particular, and Ant P solved my problem on a broader scope, I wish I could choose both as answers since they both solve my problem in two different ways, but since you solved specifically what I was trying to achieve I selected yours and I really thankful for your help, that code did the job, just needed to add () after "function" on the first line of the JS hehe

Answer (score 8):

You should delegate the parts of your layout that "need a model" to a separate controller using partial views and `RenderAction`:

```
@Html.RenderAction("SomeAction", "LayoutController")
```

Have `LayoutController.SomeAction` return a `PartialViewResult`, which you can then strongly type to a model.

Comment: thank you Ant P, I guess it is the same thing as Jasen commented, so I went through that direction, I have a child action which renders the section I need inside the _layout file and so I didn't have to tie my layout with a model and now I have a child action that simply renders what I need inside the layout, I guess this is the best solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome - Jasen's is a solid answer; I hadn't read through all the comments.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `BaseModel` to _Layout.

```
@model BaseModel
```

Then all models inherit from that BaseModel class.

```
public class MyModel : BaseModel
{
}
```

As others stated, it is not a good practice. *If your model forgets to inherit from `BaseModel`, it'll throws exception at run time.* However, it is up to you.

Comment: hey Win, thx a lot, since I'm trying to avoid bad practices I went to the direction pointed by Jasen and Ant P and created a child action to render what I needed inside the _layout file, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In BaseController you can declare any model as property.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController ()
    {
        MyTag = new TagModel ();  // or get db, take any value from there           
    }

    public TagModel MyTag { get; set; }
}
```

In action:

```
ViewBag.MyTag = MyTag ;
```

And in _Layout.cshtml, you can use

```
@{
  var myTag = (TagModel)ViewBag.MyTag;
}
```

Comment: hey Jhoon, although I really liked your idea I went to the direction noted by Ant P and Jasen and decided to create a child action, thanks a lot for the idea though, I really appreciate the help!