# Exactly why is it a bad idea to use a strongly typed _layout.cshtml in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, strong-typing

For reasons given below, strongly typing the layout seems a logical approach.

But I am scared to ignore the warnings of so many programmers so much more skilled an experienced than myself.

*Why do so many recommend avoiding this approach?*

---

**Brief Breakdown of Arguments For / Against**

I am planning to use a model like this as a base class for my application's ViewModels.

```
public class LayoutViewModel
{
    public string CanonicalURL { get; set; }
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string MetaTitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OGImage { get; set; }
    public string OGType { get; set; }
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868817/model-for-layout-cshtml-on-mvc4) generated some sensible sounding arguments ***against*** doing so, for example:

> "layout is a partial used by all of your views. Specifying a model
>   there would add restriction to every view on your site to also have
>   that model."
>
> "you are avoiding one "bad practice" (dynamic typing of ViewBag), but
>   trying to replace it with another bad practice (tying your layout to
>   model data). Layouts should not rely on data.."
>
> Ant P suggested: "You should delegate the parts of your layout that
>   "need a model" to a separate controller using partial views and
>   RenderAction"

But on reflection, I don't find them convincing:

- PageTitle, MetaTitle, Description and OG data **are required** for
  every full page view, so I feel it's proper that the ViewModel should contain
  that data.
- Why should I avoid "tying my layout to model data"? Is not every MVC view tied to the model it is based on?
- ViewBag is inconvenient and error prone

The only disadvantage I see is that layout changes may require changes to the base model also. But this seems minor compared to the advantages a strongly typed _layout.cshtml. And realistically, it's unlikely that the properties above will change any time soon.

Comment: So long as all you view models inherit from `LayoutViewModel` then I see no reason why this would be considered bad. _Layouts should not rely on data_ makes no sense - the default MVC layout includes `<title>@ViewBag.Title</title> which **is** using data (a `ViewBag` property) and AntP's comments relate more to including elements such as a menu or sidebar based on a model

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that's how it seems to me too

Comment: Depends how you look at it I suppose. Having to inherit from `LayoutViewModel` would be a pain in my eyes. Personally I would take a more modular approach and use `PartialView`s or `Section`s. In my Layout I use a section to handle things like META tags for instance. I just set the tags values in each view and it in turn places the relevant code into the Layout when rendered.

Comment: It's late but would you please demonstrate how you would implement actions/views related to CRUD operations (Edit for example)?